# What is the meaning of "The Power of Six" title?

Tags: lorien-legacies

To clarify the question - all books from the Lorien Legacies have a title that contains a number referring to one of the Garde. I.e. "The Rise of Nine" or "The Revenge of Seven".

"The Power of Six" looks the same, however in the translation that I read, the meaning of the title is changed. In there "six" refers to the six remaining living Garde and not to Number Six.

Is this a correct translation? Did the authors really make an exception for the style of the title of the second book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to an [interview with the book's author](http://hollywoodcrush.mtv.com/2011/08/23/power-of-six-pittacus-lore-interview/), the title is intended ambiguously:

> **Hollywood Crush:** *Your latest is titled "The Power of Six" but revolves quite a bit around Number Seven. How did you decide on the
>   title, and were you worried there would be any confusion that the book
>   was about Six?*
>
> **Pittacus Lore:** *The title "**The Power of Six**" refers to the remaining six Lorien who are on Earth, and their collective power, but
>   also Number Six whose power is on full display near the end of the
>   book.*

Comment: (Spoiler Alert) Nice catch :). I wonder how did they decide on that though. Actually there are seven Garde still alive (with Ella appearing) and we see the "power" of only five of them during this book. We don't see Number Five or Number Eight until the latter books.